# Entering grouped data for single feature in ArcGIS Desktop attribute tables?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table

I have single objects, polygons of different zones. Each zone has been surveyed multiple times - ie. Zone A (one polygon) may have been surveyed in 2004, 2008, and 2012 and each year has several data fields (population, temperature, etc). In R I would structure my dataframe using "group_by" commands so that Zone A was the common thread between each survey line making for easy queries. How can I group these data in a similar way in ArcMap 10.3?

Ultimately, I want to be able to create a map symbolized by the number of surveys that occurred in each Zone, but retain all information from multiple surveys. I do not want a layer for each survey, just a single layer containing all Zones and survey data. I have dozens of zones and >150 surveys, so joins seem inefficient.

I've been reading to try to figure this out but think I lack the ArcGIS terminology to effectively search for what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the tool that you are after is Summary Statistics which enables you to specify one or more fields to group by.

Comment: So each zone is a feature class of its own? Could you add a screenshot to make it easier to understand?